# Array of objects each object holds an array of items want to add items to the array

Tags: iphone, ios, nsmutablearray

I am working on my first app for the app store. I have done programming before but this is my first iOS app.

My problem requires a bit of explaintion: 
I got this app based on tableviews. It consists of following: My main screen (screen A), add item screen (screen B), detail screen (screen C) and final a add detail item screen (screen D).

All my screens segues from screen A. Screen A consists of an array with objects. Each object holds an array of detail. When you touch on a row/object in screen A, you are segued to screen C where you can see all the details for the given row/object.

I got my delegate working between screen A to screen B.

But whats giving me headache is when I want to add details to a given object in screen A. I want to be able to add a detail object to my object in screen A but how do I access my objects array when its already in an array?

```
- (void)addBudgetViewController:(AddBudgetViewController *)controller didFinishAddingItem:(Budgets *)budget
{

int newRowIndex = [self.dataModel.budgetsList count];
[self.dataModel.budgetsList addObject:budget];

NSLog(@"Budget added");

NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:newRowIndex inSection:0];
NSArray *indexPaths = [NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath];
[self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPaths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];

[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

}

Here is how I am adding items from screen B to screen A. My budgetsInList is an mutable array of budgets in screen A. But how wound the code look like if I want to add items to the objects array in the budgetsInList array?

[image: Screens]

[image: Arrays]

Array A is the list of budgets you can see in screen A. Array B is the array inside array A (also mutable). Screen B and D is add budgets to Screen A and add items to Screen C.

```
- (void)addItemViewController:(AddItemViewController *)controller didFinishAddingItem:(Item *)item
{
int newRowIndex = [self.budgets.items count];
[[self.dataModel.budgetsList objectAtIndex:newRowIndex] addObject:item];

NSLog(@"Item with name %@ added", item.name);

NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:newRowIndex inSection:0];
NSArray *indexPaths = [NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath];
[self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPaths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];

[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

}

Here is what I am trying so fare, but this would not work because I am adding the item object to the budgetsList array which is a budget array. What I want is to add the item object to the item array (array B). But how do I do that?

Hope this helps with some pic. :-)

Thanks
Regards Anders H. Opstrup

Comment: never really had succes adding mutable array into array/dictionaries either. Try and see if changing budgetsList into a mutable array works

Answer (score 0):

I have to admit that that is hard to understand your question, anyway I try to answer to something that seems clear :

> But how wound the code look like if I want to add items to the objects array in the budgetsInList array?

let's that you have this two array :

> Array A and Array B, Both mutable.

your situation if I have understood is more or less like this : Array B is an object (the only one in the example) inside the array A, and you want to add an object to the Array B

```
[[arrayA objectAtIndex:index_of_array_b_in_a] addObject:the_object_you_want_add]
```

Let me know if this was your problem.

Comment: Sorry for the bad explanation :-(. Yep both my arrays are mutable. I will try to rephrase problem. I have two Arrays, array A and array B. Both mutable. Array A Holds objects, each object in array A contains an array, array B. I would like to add items to array B in my delegate method. Hopes this makes it a bit more clear :)

Answer (score 0):

If array A is an array of arrays, then [arrayA objectAtIndex:0], for instance, will give you the first array (an arrayB in your explanation). So, to add an object to the first array in arrayA, just do this:

```
[[arrayA objectAtIndex:0] addObject:anObject];
```

Comment: I can not make it to work, but I have just edited my post with some pic maybe this will help? :) Thank you